# What is the simplest way to send an anonymous email?

Tags: email, anonymity

I would like to send an email that can't be traced back to me, is there a simple direct approach to do that?

I mean an electronic way that doesn't involve me going to an Internet cafe wearing a hoodie in order to avoid cameras.

- I need no response
- Obviously I don't want my email to be flagged as spam and never gets noticed.
- I would like to report a serious issue to the authorities, I would like to remain anonymous because I don't want to testify.

Comment: Get a Hotmail account?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage seriously? MicroSoft supports anonymity now-days?

Comment: Do you need to receive a response on the mails? If not you could use a [temporary email address](https://www.guerrillamail.com/)

Comment: @BadSkillz That changes nothing if the temporary email provider keeps logs and can hand them to the authorities

Comment: @Ulkoma If you trust no-one then you might find things very difficult. Also bear in mind that emails lacking an identifiable source (in the form of SPF and DKIM records) are liable to be caught by spam filters. Maybe http://mail2tor.com/ is more up your street.

Comment: The big question is: do you need to get a response of any sort? Secondarily, are you concerned about it getting caught by a spam filter (users with high volume mailboxes, such as corporate email accounts, will use heavier filters since the addresses are publicized and subject to more spam).  Also, include how your question is different from this one: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24570/how-can-i-send-emails-anonymously?rq=1

Comment: Sorry for the countless follow ups but this is a very nuanced subject.  The final answer to your question rests on how sensitive the information you are emailing will be.  For example, if you are emailing someone to tell them you are a secret admirer (and do so without any illegal intent) then any email provider will suffice; since while you are not anonymous to the provider, they will hold your identity in confidence.  If you are emailing state secrets as a whistleblower and hope to evade prosecution, wherein the provider will divulge all their data, you obviously need a different approach.

Comment: If what you have to say is important, why not just use regular mail without a return address? It's much more likely to be read that way.

Comment: If you want a reply anyway but stay anonymous, check https://posteo.de/en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)
2. Using Tor Browser, go to a site like [Send Anonymous Email](http://www.sendanonymousemail.net/)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 :**

There is a lot of annymous email sender through the web just do some googling

here is a list providing you 20 Sites To Keep Your Identity Hidden

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/anonymous-email-providers/

if you want to receive back an answer you could use yopmail.com (no need to create an account)

**Solution 2 :**

You could setup a gmail/yahoo account using a proxy(normal) or  [torbrowser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and when they ask for phone verification you could use a fake number generated by services such :

- http://receivesmsonline.com/
- https://www.textnow.com/
- http://receive-sms.com/
- http://www.pinger.com/tfw/

these services gives you the verification sms to confirm your account. So your account will be linked to a fake number and your identity will remain unknown

Comment: Gmail, and likely Yahoo, block all tor exit nodes for registering email. Have you even tried the things you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

Use Tor Deep Web Email provider services

- OnionMail
- SIGAINT (No Javascript Needed)
- MailTor
- Mail2Tor

  You Need Tor Onion Links For All Of them just search on google and easily you find links